# Why is Luke Cage hiding in Pop's barbershop?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, luke-cage-2016, luke-cage

The newly released Netflix show [*Luke Cage*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3322314/?ref_=nv_sr_2) is another series operating in the Marvel Cinematic Universe and it's closely related to Daredevil and Jessica Jones, especially since Luke was a character in the latter as one of Jessica's love interests.

Now, if my memory is right [*Jessica Jones*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2357547/?ref_=nv_sr_3) ends with her and Luke <s>still being together</s> being relatively close, and the settings of *Luke Cage* take place several months after that episode.  This seems to be confirmed when he tells Pop

> he got shot point blank in the chin in one of the "JJ"  episode that "even now gives him headaches"

But why is he hiding, living away from Jessica, getting paid under the table and struggling to pay the rent? He wasn't exactly poor previously and even if he lost most of his income

> when his pub was burned down

he still could get a decent, legal job (even Pop mentions that he could pay him more if it wasn't in cash). While Luke does have a bit of illegal backstory, his current ID had to be at least good enough to give him alcohol license to work in his own pub.

Comment: There was a line when he was talking to Pop about him being framed, but I don't remember that happening in Jessica Jones.

Comment: He was framed (before JJ) by Diamondback as I understand it...which ended up with him being sent to Seagate.

Comment: He mentions being a fugitive on several occasions.

Comment: Sure but this didn't seem to be an issue during Jessica Jones as Yassiker stated.

Comment: Yes, he was a legitimate pub owner in JJ series, which implies liquor license obtained after police checks.

Comment: “Jessica Jones ends with her and Luke still being together” — really? I think Luke decides after Jessica shoots him in the head, having previously found out that she killed his wife (albeit while under the control of Kilgrave).

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - Yeah, you're right.  They had broken up shortly after he found out about his wife's death, and their later grouping up again was entirely Kilgrave using him to get to her.  He vanishes from the apartment and is not seen again as soon as he recovers from the gunshot concussion.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite you're right, I stand corrected. I thought he and JJ met up again after the shooting in the chin incident.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We never get any explanation for what happened during the period between *Jessica Jones* and *Luke Cage*, but the best explanation for why Cage was working at Pops is that he had gone into hiding after the Kilgrave affair.

Remember that Cage was a fugitive from the law. He had sunk all of his money into opening his bar and trying to keep a "low profile". Also, when he opened the bar, Reva was still alive, so any paperwork they needed, she could have handled to keep his name off of it.

His bar explodes after Kilgrave had him blow the bar up. Even though he was being mind controlled, that would probably make getting an insurance payout complicated. On top of that, he was becoming involved in high-profile incidents around Hells Kitchen, the kind of thing he was trying to avoid.

Instead, Cage appears to have decided to abandon Hells Kitchen and go back to Harlem. He wouldn't want to take a regular job, lease an apartment, etc. because that would put him "in the system" again, and he was trying to disappear. So he took whatever jobs would pay him under the table, and an apartment that he paid for in cash.

Comment: In episode 4 we see Carl Lucas Cage escaping from jail after being made "super". Presumably he's still wanted for that?

Comment: yes, that's why he's a fugitive from the law... the feds just haven't found him yet and he's trying to keep it that way.